# Why should userspace applications lock Ebpf maps?

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

When you create EBPF maps, memory is allocated in kernel space. And kernel memory never gets swapped out. Then, why is there a need for the userspace application to call `setrlimit()` with `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` refers to the amount of memory that may be locked into RAM, it is not specific to allocations in the user space memory address range. On pre-5.11 kernels, memory used for eBPF objects (programs, maps, BTF objects etc.) is accounted against this resource, meaning that if you create too many of them at a given time, or even in a short interval of time (given that there is a small delay after the deletion of an object before the kernel reclaims the corresponding memory area), you may hit the resource limit and get a `-EPERM` as an answer. For privileged users, calling `setrlimit()` to lift the restrictions on this resource is the usual workaround indeed.

Note that in Linux 5.11, [rlimit-based accounting was dropped in favour of cgroup-based memory accounting](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20201201215900.3569844-1-guro@fb.com/t/#u). The rlimit had a number of downsides (refer to the cover letter linked above for details), and the cgroup-based accounting is more flexible, while allowing a better control and offering easier ways to retrieve the current amount of memory used. It should also reflect the actual memory consumption, while this was not necessarily the case with rlimit.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. Does libbpf mlock() on the ebpf map memory area?
2. If yes, why is that so? Maps reside in the kernel memory, so they are never meant to be swapped out, which means there is no need for a mlock() call.

I understand that setrlimit() helps to increase the ceiling for mlock(). However, what I don't get is why in the first place should a user space application mlock() kernel pages.

Comment: No, libbpf does _not_ `mlock()` the map memory area (save for a few specific use cases). But it's not a matter of what user space does. As soon as a user creates an eBPF program or map on Linux <= 5.10, the kernel accounts for the size of the reserved area and checks the total against the `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` for this user. Nothing to do with user space running `mlock()` on the objects. The name of the limit is misleading in this case.